# Как выровнить большую картинку в блоке по вертикали в css

Tags: html, css

Имеется блок, высота и ширина динамические относительно параметров экрана. Внутри этого блока картина больших размеров. Как её вставить чётко по середине картинки по вертикали в этом блоке. Скриншот приложил[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

нашёл решение

```
.item {
  position: relative;
  overflow:  hidden;
  height: 300px;
}

.item img {
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: -50%;
  bottom: -50%;
  right: -50%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: А зачем вы выравниваете по горизонтали тоже?

Comment: `нашёл решение`, ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста, [со справкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).